# Citrix Workspace App on Ubuntu 19.04: Cannot find the file /opt/Citrix/ICAClient//config/appsrv.ini

Tags: 19.04, citrix

I am trying to make Citrix Workspace app v19.6.0.60 to run on Ubuntu 19.04.

Installation works fine, but when I start the app, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find the file: (/opt/Citrix/ICAClient//config/appsrv.ini).
Please check your installation or contact your help desk.
```

In the mentioned folder there is no `appsrv.ini` but an `appsrv.template`. Anyone knows whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ...

- deleting .ICAClient folder in user home
- import mozillla certifcates
- download the ica file and start citrix with this file

... it finally worked

Found the solution here: https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/404634-citrix-workspace-app-on-ubuntu-1904-cannot-find-the-file-optcitrixicaclientconfigappsrvini/